# What are the axioms of personalism?

Tags: axiom, personalism

I've read some authors whose works are held as belonging to personalism.

However while their works elaborated based on principles of personalism, they never clearly explained what the axioms were that personalism bases itself on.

[One brief example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personalism#Boston_personalism):

> Bowne also held that persons have value (see axiology, value theory, and ethics). **In declaring the absolute value of personhood**, he stood firmly against certain forms of philosophical naturalism (including social Darwinism) which sought to reduce the value of persons.

So what could be considered the axioms of personalism?

Comment: A few words about it. First, the so called Tree of Porphyry. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyrian_tree Note it ends on an individual person. So this was the individual’s relationship with God (this was the view, anyway).  This to be compared to mass systems such as socialism and fascism.  Personalism was the middle way.  Mounier’s work is probably the best treatment of it because he brings in Blondel toward the end of the book. An English translation of Mounier’s “Personalism” is sometimes available on Internet Archive.

Comment: None. Philosophy is not mathematics, philosophical systems and schools of thought do not have "axioms", only common  maxims, intuitions and loose principles, at best. Not even  all of them are universally shared by all, and there is a great deal of variation in specifics of interpreting and applying those that are by different authors. You can read a general overview in [SEP, Personalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/personalism/)

Comment: There is an introductory book on personalism by Emmanuel Mounier, the leading french philosopher of personalism  (PUF,  " Que sais-je? " collection ). He states clearly in this book the principles of this doctrne.